# Magnification problems of Java Apps under Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, resolution, magnification

I am using Windows 10 Pro 64bit.

My monitor (32inch) has a native resolution of 3820 * 2160 pixels.

As soon when I use Java based applications I have problems with the magnification of fonts, buttons, etc. Often they are too small.

I know I can change the overall scaling of all elements to more than 100%. But this leads to the fact that fonts etc. are blurred.

Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Did you read this: http://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display

Comment: @mrz  A screen shot would help to understand the scenario.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most common solution (try google) is **disable DPI awareness**. You can do this by running your app with:

```
-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false
```

Note that, here is bug for Java 8 :( See [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8080153) ticket.